# Why does Web Print keep moving image(s) to the left?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, printing, twitter-bootstrap-2

I am formatting the html on a page so that it prints onto a piece of standard A4 sized paper in a certain way.

At the top of the page, I would like to render an image *in the middle*

I am using twitter bootstrap classes to try to accomplish this.

```
<div class="row-fluid">          
<div class="span4"></div>
<div class="span4">
<img class="center-block" src="../../../Content/design/css/img/thepicture.png" />
</div>
<div class="span4"></div>
</div>
```

Problem: when the print-preview dialog opens (google Chrome browser), the image is always flush on the left.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you post a JS Fiddle or JS Bin of your example?

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to print a page the CSS will usually be off. What you need to do is specify a print stylesheet that has custom styles for printing:

You will need to use a media query to specify the contents for printing.

```
@media print {
    // Custom CSS
}
```